# Tab Layout with round corners - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, tabs

I want to create a TabLayout like this:

[image]

But it's coming Like :

[image: image2]

This is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabIndicator="@drawable/bg_tabs_select"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/black" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be because you are having a white background for unselected tabs so the rounded corner is not visible.

Use `app:tabBackground="#0000"`
or instead you can have a drawable to have different background color when selected and for unselected tabs.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark"      
        android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

Instead of #0000 use your desired color.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this piece of code for the below output**

[image]

- This is TabLayout in activity.xml file

  ```
   <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_bg_inset"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/NormalTextStyle"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
            app:tabMode="auto"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="55dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="20dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="20dp"
            app:tabRippleColor="@color/transparent"
            app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_active_bg"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabIndicatorGravity="center"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/text_color_black" />
  ```
- This is tab background tab_bg_inset.xml file set padding start and end in tab background

  ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg"
            android:insetRight="5dp"
            android:insetLeft="5dp" />
  ```
- This is an unselected tab set in the tab background tab_bg.xml file

  ```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:top="8dp"
            android:bottom="8dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/screen_bg"/>
                <corners android:radius="25dp"/>
                <size android:height="50dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
  ```
- This is the selected tab_active_bg.xml file

  ```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:top="8dp"
            android:bottom="8dp"
            android:end="5dp"
            android:start="5dp">
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
               <solid android:color="@color/color_accent"/>
               <corners android:radius="25dp"/>
               <size android:height="50dp"/>
           </shape>
       </item>
   </layer-list>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

tab_background.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--non-selected tab -->
<item android:state_selected="false">
    <layer-list>
        <!-- Border -->
        <item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#E1E1E1" />
                <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:left="6dp" android:right="6dp" android:top="6dp" android:bottom="6dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
                <corners android:radius="18dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

<!--selected tab -->
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <layer-list>
        <!-- Background -->
        <item android:left="6dp" android:right="6dp" android:top="6dp" android:bottom="6dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/forest_green" />
                <corners android:radius="18dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
...
app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"/>
```